# Angular application is not reloading if i focus on the address bar and click enter in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

For one of my Single page application (Angular js ) is having trouble with firefox,

Where if i place cursor and hit enter in address bar the app is not reloading.

Tested in Firefox version 38 , and also tried in IE10 and chrome its fit and fine ;)

url is something like *www.StudentApplication.com/client.app/app/#/studentSearch*

Note : Firebug is not showing any network traffic upon clicking enter.

Please suggest some solution

Comment: can you provide an example of this?  some code, or a plunker of the issue?

Comment: I think it's because of the # in the url. You need to remove it by using html5mode or you can just relax and leave it as is. Why would you need it to reload?